# OPENCV bitwise_and operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I am learning OpenCV library in python following the tutorials and examples. I arrived to bitwise operations.

In this typical example:

```
   # Load two images
img1 = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')

# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]

# Now create a mask of logo and create its inverse mask also
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)

# Put logo in ROI and modify the main image
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst

cv2.imshow('res',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When bitwise_and is used I don't understand what makes each parameter, and I've checked a hundred tutorials and no one clarifies it. What I don't understand is why we use twice roi in the parameters because "anyArray AND anyArray = anyArray".

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: It may seem confusing, since this is the way to do it in python. In c++ you can do mat.copyTo(mat2,mask) and then it will copy it without doing any operation... in python you have numpy arrays and not cv::mat, and it is easier to just use this operation that won't change the image and permits the use of a mask (only copies where white pixels are in the mask). In one channel images you can do `bitwiseAnd` directly with the mask and you will get the same effect. But when you have 3 channels you need to either make a 3 channel mask or do this "trick"